# SVG rotation using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, svg

I have created an SVG image in an HTML page, and now I want to move the SVG shapes about using
JavaScript buttons. The JSFiddle for my application is here : http://jsfiddle.net/johndavies91/xwMYY/

The buttons have been displayed but their functions aren't being displayed upon clicking the buttons.

The functions' codes are as follows;

```
function rotatex() {
document.getElementById("inner-arrow").setRotate(45,NativeCenterX,NativeCenterY)
}
function rotatey() {
document.getElementById("middle-arrow").setRotate(45,NativeCenterX,NativeCenterY)
}
function rotatez() {
document.getElementById("outer-arrow").setRotate(45,NativeCenterX,NativeCenterY)
}
```

and their corresponding buttons;

```
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Rotate Inner Short Arrows 45*"
        onclick="rotatex()"/>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Rotate Middle Short Arrows 45*"
        onclick="rotatey()"/>
<input id="button1" type="button" value="Rotate Outer Short Arrows 45*"
        onclick="rotatez()"/>
```

I am trying to rotate them around the shapes' origin. Could someone explain to me
why this code isn't working. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever succeed using `setRotate()`? If there is browser support for it I believe it's quite recent, but you can always use `setAttribute('transform','rotate(...)')` with the same result.

Comment: I tested your fiddle and it seems that your JS is not executing because `rotatex` is undefined (turn on the JavaScript console in your browser to see these errors). If will fork if you place it in the `<head>` (see how this working [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/xwMYY/1/) is configured)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2da4B/

This uses `.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(45)")` instead of `setRotate`:

```
function rotatex() {
    var innerArrow = document.getElementById("inner-arrow");
    innerArrow.setAttribute("transform", "rotate(45)");
}
```

This rotates 45 degrees around the `0,0` origin - it's not clear from your question whether that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, I was looking to rotate the arrows around their origins, i.e. the center of each arrow. Also I would like to be able to click the button multiple times. Thanks!

Comment: Hi - see http://jsfiddle.net/2da4B/1/ for the subsequent clicks issue. For rotation origin, it's going to be much easier if you define your polygons with the origin at the point you want to use for rotation.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing id's by replacing `-`(dash) with `_` (underscore).

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you to use external library for SVG works. For example - Raphaël. .

Here is the link http://raphaeljs.com . With help of this lib you will easily be able to complete your task.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not looking to use an external library to complete this.

Comment: in this case, i guess those links can help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/FrEeA/

http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/blog/svg-animation-rotating-elements