# Dynamically draw/turn SVG with variable input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I want to dynamically draw/turn an SVG with React from degree paramters that im recieving. Its like the direction arrow from a weather-info. [image]

1. How do I dynamically draw an SVG in Javascript / ReactJS?
2. How do I turn the SVG with variable input?

I'm aware, that you can draw SVG-Graphics like this:

```
function draw_square() {
    var draw = SVG('square_1');
    draw.size(120, 120);
    var square = draw.rect(100, 100);
    square.attr({ fill: '#f06' });
}
 
draw_square()
```

but how do I connect different svg-paths to each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend a slightly different approach:

```
const WindDirectionIcon = ({ width, height }) => {
  return (
    <svg
      id="wind-direction-arrow"
      width={width}
      height={height}
      viewBox="0 0 12 12"
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <path d="M6 0L0 12L6 9L12 12L6 0Z" fill="black" />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const degrees = 90; // Retrieve from your API
    const arrow = document.getElementById("wind-direction-arrow");
    arrow.setAttribute("transform", `rotate(${degrees})`);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <WindDirectionIcon width="24" height="24" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

So the svg itself can be composed of a single path and the only thing we do with javascript is to set the `transform` attribute to rotate a certain number of degrees based on the API data you receive using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Rotate with javascript based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116603/9098350).

[Sandbox Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-glade-fkfzz?file=/src/App.js:441-491)

Comment: Thanks very much. I set the content of your useEffect into my API-Call useEffect.. One question though. How did you know what path-data the SVG needed?

Comment: In this instance I used a graphic design tool to create the svg. I used [figma](http://figma.com/). It allows you to create shapes using a pen tool or by combining more primative shapes into one. If you've created a graphic, figma allows you to right click and copy as svg. You can also find documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) on how svg paths work in general. So you could also create the paths manually, but most shapes you tend to want to create are fairly complex, so I recommend the first approach most of the time.